AppleScript - can't click Save (name) field
A repeating script types the name of a file in the Save dialog.
Sometimes the name field isn't selected so I want to click it with "click at {1080, 188}"... but nothing happens.
The coords are correct as I've tested the menu also in the dialog which works fine.
Doesn't work in Apple Preview or Chrome.
on run {input, parameters}
    delay 3
    tell application "System Events"
        click at {1080, 188}  -- does nothing, the save field
        delay 3
        click at {1010, 725}  -- works, clicks the menu
        delay 3
    end tell
    return input
end run

Thanks.

Better than using unreliable click at set the value of the text field and click the button. Both don't require focus.

I don't find Applescript unreliable.

I said unreliable click at

The answer is the dialog is not named "Save As", it's a window belonging to the window from which it was generated.
    -- focus on Save As field
    tell process "((the app name))"
        -- Ensure the correct window is frontmost
        set frontmost to true
        repeat with w in windows
            if name of w is "((title of the window that sourced the Save dialog...a dialog is not a window))" then
                set index of w to 1
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        
        -- Check if the Save dialog is open
        if exists sheet 1 of window 1 then
            tell sheet 1 of window 1
                -- Focus on the "Save As" field
                if exists text field 1 then
                    set value of text field 1 to "" -- Optionally clear the field
                    set focused of text field 1 to true
                end if
            end tell
        end if
    end tell

